# Logger with host name

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have an application running in load balancing servers. 
The number of log files generated are equal to the number of servers. How can we name the log files as per the server names.
I am using commons.log4j

Answer (score 0):

```
<Property name="hostname">${env:HOSTNAME}</Property>

reference it like ${hostname}.log
```

Comment: Andy, I am getting the host name dynamically from java class. How can I use this?

Comment: if you use java code to get the host name, you can use System.setProperty('hostname',hostname), after that, you can use ${hostname} in your log4j configuration file.